Perfmon Metrics Collector plugin not working in JMeter. What could be the issue?
I have installed the perfmon metric collector plugin in JMeter. I have downloaded the startAgent.bat file from GITHUB repository. I run the startAgent.bat file. The agent is started. But when I try to execute or validate, the startAgent.bat will immediately shut down. Then nothing happens. Graphs and charts are not generated. What could be the issue? Please forward your solution. Thank You!
I tried to add the port number in the jmeter.properties file but the result is the same.

sharing some screenshots regarding the issue would make it more meaningful

Unfortunately we cannot help you without seeing the PerfMon Agent console output and/or debug log.
One of the reasons I can think of is: you're running the Server Agent on 64-bit Windows it might be the case you're suffering from SIGAR bug #136
The solution is to re-build the sigar-amd64-winnt.dll library with 64-bit dependencies and replace the one in the Server Agent distribution with the recompiled one. Once done the issue will go away.
If you trust random people in the Internet you can take a fixed version from Github
More infromation: How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test
